# Объединение двух таблиц (JOIN), группирование (GROUP BY) по двум параметрам из одной из них и арифметические операции с ними

Tags: sql, база-данных, join, group-by

Всем привет. 
У меня есть две таблицы (MySQL-8.0-Win10):

*Создаю первую таблицу*

```
CREATE TABLE `products` ( `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,                                               
`product_name` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,                                  
`product_unit` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,                                         
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

*Создаю вторую таблицу*

```
CREATE TABLE `products_operations` ( `product_id` INT NOT NULL , 
`operation_status` INT NOT NULL ,                        
`operation_size` DECIMAL(11,4) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

*Добавляю данные в первую таблицу*

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `product_unit`) 
VALUES ('1', 'Песок', 'м3'), ('2', 'Песок', 'т'),                   
('3', 'Цемент', 'т'), ('4', 'Щебень', 'м3');
```

*Добавляю данные во вторую таблицу*

```
INSERT INTO `products_operations` (`product_id`, `operation_status`, `operation_size`)                                                      
VALUES ('1', '1', '3000'), ('1', '2', '2500'), ('2', '1', '1000'),  
('2', '2', '750'), ('2', '2', '50'), ('3', '1', '100'), ('4', '1', '500'),                                                                 
('1', '1', '100');
```

***products (Таблица 1)*** - список товаров

| product_id (id товара) | product_name (имя товара) | product_unit (ед. изм. товара) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Песок | м3 |
| 2 | Песок | т |
| 3 | Цемент | т |
| 4 | Щебень | м3 |

***products_operations (Таблица 2)*** - операции с товарами

| product_id (id товара) | operation_status (1 - приход, 2 - расход) | operation_size (объем операции) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 000,00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 500,00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 000,00 |
| 2 | 2 | 750,00 |
| 2 | 2 | 50,00 |
| 3 | 1 | 100,00 |
| 4 | 1 | 500,00 |
| 1 | 1 | 100,00 |

***Моя задача вывести в браузер следующие данные:***

| product_name (имя товара) | product_unit (ед. изм. товара) | приход (сумма всех приходов (operation_status = 1) по параметру product_name (имя товара) + product_unit (ед. изм. товара) | расход (сумма всех расходов (operation_status = 2) по параметру product_name (имя товара) + product_unit (ед. изм. товара) | остаток (разность всех приходов и расходов по параметру product_name (имя товара) + product_unit (ед. изм. товара) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Песок | м3 | 3 100,00 | 2 500,00 | 600,00 |
| Песок | т | 1 000,00 | 800,00 | 200,00 |
| Цемент | т | 100,00 | 0,00 | 100,00 |
| Щебень | м3 | 500,00 | 0,00 | 500,00 |

Как вытащить суммы приходов и расходов по-отдельности для каждого product_name (имя продукта), я понимаю. Трудность для меня в том, чтобы вытащить данные для пары product_name (имя товара) + product_unit (ед. изм. товара).
Если нужно, могу свои кривые варианты скинуть. Но ни один из них не работает.
Спасибо.

**upd.**
Изначально задача стояла вывести только приход. И так как объем прихода был в таблице products, то запрос был такой:

```
SELECT product_name, product_unit,                                               
SUM(product_size) AS sum_product_size                                
FROM products                                                       
GROUP BY product_name, product_unit                                 
ORDER BY sum_product_size DESC;
```

Далее добавилась еще одна таблица (product_operations) и запросы для расхода и остатка у меня выглядели так:

*Получаю сумму прихода:*

```
$income_sum = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT SUM(operation_size) as sum 
FROM `products_operations`                                          
WHERE `product_id` = '$prdct_id' AND `operation_status` = '1'");
                                                                
$incm_sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($income_sum);
$incm_sm = $incm_sum['sum'];
```

В этом и затык, что $prdct_id это айди продукта без привязки к паре (product_id + product_unit).

*Далее получаю сумму расхода:*

```
$spending_sum = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT SUM(operation_size) as sum                                                                      
FROM `products_operations`                                          
WHERE `product_id` = '$prdct_id' AND `operation_status` = '2'");
                                                              
$spndng_sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($spending_sum);                                                           
$spndng_sm = $spndng_sum['sum'];
```

*И чтобы в итоге получить остаток, делаю следующее:*

```
$balance_sum = $incm_sm - $spndng_sm;
```

**upd2.**
На данный момент пришел к такому виду запроса:

```
SELECT products.product_name, products.product_unit, products_operations.operation_status, 
SUM(products_operations.operation_size) as sum_product_size          
FROM products                                                        
JOIN products_operations                                               
ON products.product_id = products_operations.product_id             
GROUP BY product_name, product_unit                                 
ORDER BY sum_product_size DESC
```

Однако, я получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'products_operations.operation_status' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in...

Это, вроде как, из за того, что в SELECT есть products_operations.operation_status, а в GROUP BY его нет. Но как решить эту проблему, я пока не понял

**upd3.**
Решение, вроде как, найдено. Помог разобраться @Mike.
Команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT products.product_name, products.product_unit, 
SUM(products_operations.operation_size * 
(products_operations.operation_status = 1)) as sum_product_size_income, 
SUM(products_operations.operation_size * 
(products_operations.operation_status = 2)) as sum_product_size_spending    
FROM products                                                        
JOIN products_operations                                               
ON products.product_id = products_operations.product_id                          
GROUP BY product_name, product_unit                                 
ORDER BY sum_product_size_1 DESC
```

Спасибо большое!

Comment: Для начала нужно: 1) заменить или дополнить таблицы набором CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, позволяющим воспроизвести данные, либо ссылкой на online fiddle; 2) Указать точно СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: *Если нужно, могу свои кривые варианты скинуть.* Конечно, нужно. Причём обязательно с объяснением  того, какая логика была заложена в запрос - ведь косяк именно в ней.

Comment: Отличие получения по паре product_name + product_unit от получения по  product_name только в том, что в `group by` у вас должен быть не product_name, а `product_name, product_unit`

Comment: @Mike если все данные находятся в одной таблице, я представляю, как выглядит запрос. Но в моем случае, часть данных находится в другой таблице

Comment: как обычные запросы с join пишутся знаете ? вот, сначала делаете запрос с join, потом добавляете в него нужные sum и group by

Comment: норм выглядит. но вам вроде надо было получить суммы для разных статусов, так что лучше как то так https://pastebin.com/HZwEbDxG

Comment: @Mike Спасибо_!